# Synchronizing issue with delays in loops

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization

I'm trying to delay specific threads inside a loop and I am not getting the behavior I want. I would like `1B` to run only once `1A` has been completed, while `2A` runs in parallel on a separate thread. My implementation runs `1A` then `1B` then `2A` instead. Any idea how I can fix this?

**Implementation**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loopManager(printable: "1A") // 1A
        self.loopManager(printable: "1B") // 1B
    }

    // 2
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loopManager(printable: "2A") // 2A
    }
}

func loopManager(printable: String) {
    for i in 0...3 {
        doABC(printable: String(i) + ", " + printable)
        sleep(1)
    }
}

func doABC(printable: String) {
    print(printable)
}
```

**Logs**

```
0, 1A
1, 1A
2, 1A
3, 1A
0, 1B
1, 1B
2, 1B
3, 1B
0, 2A
1, 2A
2, 2A
3, 2A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your code in the same thread. You need to run `2A` in another thread.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    self.loopManager(printable: "2A") // 2A
}
```

Output sample:

```
0, 1A
0, 2A
1, 2A
1, 1A
2, 1A
2, 2A
3, 1A
3, 2A
0, 1B
1, 1B
2, 1B
3, 1B
```