# Delaying iterations of a for loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, sprite-kit, delay

I have been struggling with this for awhile.  I have a for loop which is creating an group of SKSpriteNodes and giving them physics etc.  This seems to be causing a lag in gameplay when this loop is run.  I have successfully delayed the actual adding of the spriteNodes but this doesn't seem to help with the lag issue.  I would like to be able to have the for loop run once, wait for a bit of time, then run the next iteration.  Is this possible?

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

func createRoadImages() {
    for (index, roadImage) in imageArrays.enumerated() {
        print(imageArrays)
        let roadSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: roadImage)
        roadSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        roadSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(screenCounter) * roadSprite.size.height)
        roadSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.friction = roadFriction
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.mass = backgroundMass
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = damping
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.RoadImageCategory.rawValue
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.NoCollisionsCategory.rawValue
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.BroomCategory.rawValue
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        roadSprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

        roadSprite.zPosition = 1
        roadSprite.name = "Road \(index)"

        delay(delayFor * Double(index)) {
            self.addChild(roadSprite)
            print("Sprite added \(index)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe put the code in [`update`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519802-update)?

Comment: Encountered something a bit similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527755/synchronizing-issue-with-delays-in-loops

Comment: Where are you calling this function from?

Comment: I would recommend rethinking your strategy,  something like this should be done during the loading phase of your game.

Comment: This function is being called in the update function when the player's position gets to a certain point.  It's purpose is to create the background ahead of the player

Comment: if the idea is to do on the fly loading, then you want to place this in a background thread by using `DispatchQueue.global`, but even with on the fly loading, a lot of your assets can be done during the loading and then just copied.  If the only difference between your physics body is how big the square is, then a good trick is to make a single sub node of a particular size, and then scale the node to the size of the node you need the body for.  This allows you to rapidly make physics bodies.

Comment: thanks for that KnightOfDragon, I will try something along those lines, and may bug you again as I go.